# modify 128 bytes

Tags: linux, video, php

I have to replace on a Linux web server, the first 128 bytes of some binary files.

The files have a size of ~ 5Gb and I just have to rewrite the header bytes. What would be the best approach to do this using Linux native commands or even PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply open the file in "append" or similar mode, seek to position 0, then write your data.

---

"Linux native commands": the syscalls (or their libc wrappers) are as close as you can get.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main() {
    char buf[128] = "this and that";
    int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, &buf, sizeof(buf));
    close(fd);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$buf = "this and that";
$fh = fopen("file", "a" "r+");
fseek($fh, 0);
fwrite($fh, $buf);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: It would have been nice if I could test the php solution, but as it is, doesn't work (If you have opened the file in append (a or a+) mode, any data you write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file position, and the result of calling fseek() will be undefined. )

Comment: @Xander: That is an ... *interesting* design decision from PHP's side. Try opening the file as `c` or `r+`, then. (Is this actually documented anywhere?)

Comment: Ah, I found it under `fseek()`. Sigh.

Comment: @Xander: I suggest encoding them with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (PHP has `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` for that) and sending them over POST. **Don't forget proper authentication**!

Comment: @grawity That's not PHP's fault, "a" is equivalent to opening with O_APPEND, and is documented in the equivalent C functions (both `open` and `fopen`)

Comment: @Random832: Thanks, didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 13):

The `dd` is a simple approach.

```
dd if=128bytefile of=videofiletofix.mkv bs=128 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

So this will take the first 128 bytes of a file called `128bytefile` and overwrite the first 128 bytes of a file called `videofiletofix.mkv`.

The `bs` parameter says to copy 128 bytes at a time, and the `count` parameter says to copy one such 128 byte block.  The `conv=notrunc` parameter is important — without it, `dd` will truncate the output file to the length of the copied data (here, 128 bytes), which is most definitely *not* what you want.

Comment: nice solution Paul, thanks for your help. I would rise a point but I'm too new around and the system does not allow :)

Comment: This is how I'd do it, excellent answer.

Comment: @Xander: You _can_ do something like `dd if=localfile  bs=128 count=1 | ssh server 'dd of=videofile conv=notrunc'`.  However, why not just copy the 128-byte file to the server first?

Comment: @Xander: You could always download [`dd` for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) and use it to extract the first 128 bytes. (Just use the same command as in the answer, but with a non-existent file as the target.)

Comment: @Xander: 1. Anything that can transfer binary files is fine. 2. Use the `dd` command given in the answer. Just to be safe, you may want to make a backup copy of the target file first, at least until you're sure you've got the hang of it.